# GO: Obtain various query results in if else block based on parameters number

Tags: variables, go, scope

I am using go-mysql-driver to make queries to my database.
I have a function In which I am passing `id` and `warehouseId`.

Now I am modifying my mysql query based on if warehouseId value is 0 or not.

The problem is the parameters that I pass in `db.Query()`.
Following is my `mysql query` where I am appending additional query if `warehouseId` is not `0`.

```
query := "select id,description from offers inner join offer_entities on offers.id = offer_entities.offer_id where offer_entities.entity_id = ?"
if warehouseId != 0 {
    query += `and offer_entities.warehouse_id = ? `
}
query += `group by offer_id`
```

I parse it like this:

```
if warehouseId != 0 {
    rows, err := db.Query(query, variantId, warehouseId)
} else {
    rows, err := db.Query(query, variantId)
}
```

However, the problem is when I run it, I get an error `undefined: rows`. I know that it is because `rows` should be defined `outside the if-else` conditions. But I don't understand how to define rows outside if-else or
If there is any other way I could achieve my requirements.

How should I tackle this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is because of variables are defined in the scope in which they are declared.

The difference between = and := is that = is just assignment and := is used for assignment and declaration

for example

```
 rows := 1 
//it basically means 
 var rows int 
 rows = 1
```

what you want is to declare rows outside the if-else and then use them, will solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

#### Scope visibility

Each block has itself visibility scope. A general rule is **visible from inner, invisible from outer**. It means you can see variables from superior scope in subject scope but not vise versa.

I believe you use `rows` declared in `if` statement out of the block, so it doesn't exist there.

```
var err error
var rows string
if warehouseId != 0 {
    rows, err := db.Query(query, variantId, warehouseId)
} else {
    rows, err := db.Query(query, variantId)
}
fmt.Println(rows) // It is now possible to use `rows` outside of the block
```

#### Declaration styles

`var name <type>` is a common declaration way. The variable with typed `nil` value will be declared.

`name := <value of type>` is a short declaration form. It will declare a variable of a type and assign a value to it at the same time. Allowed only in functions.